# Espresso and Jetpack compose for app testing

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso-recorder

I was wondering if anyone can point me to a doc about using espresso to perform a record espresso test from Android Studio.

I have read conflicting documents about whether or not espresso works with compose.  I did see an article that indicated on the official compose website they spoke of using espresso to test but I cannot find it.

I also am not sure how to set up android studio to get the record espresso test option to work with or without compose.

Any help is appreciated.